# how to keep xtrareport master child footer in same line

Tags: devexpress, report, xtrareport

i have master report and a child report i  have 2 groupfooter in master and 2 groupfooter in child i a not able to keep master and child report footer in same line

[image]

Comment: I edited your post and added the image inline.

Comment: I think it can not do so because the report has a standard line layout (can not be a master footer and child footer on the same line) you need to use some cross field component if exists?